# Where should I look at in Eclipse source code to figure out how Eclipse generate JUnit testing result?

Tags: eclipse, junit

I'm analyzing Apache ant source code for my research. When a test suite runs, test cases are executed and Eclipse shows the test result as the image below. My goal is to get the executed test case names as Eclipse does. If I can see source code where Eclipse handles this, I think I can get the name list. Therefore, I'd like to know the source code location where Eclipse handle this or an easier way to achieve the goal... I tried using JUnit task in an ant build script to generate the test report so that I can get the test list by parsing the text/xml report. I could get the report with some warnings stating that duplicate classes are detected because I'm testing ant with ant. However, the report showed the test method name without its full class name...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a short workaround for what you want to achieve (to have a specific, deterministic test run order), it is the [@FixMethodOrder](http://junit.czweb.org/apidocs/org/junit/FixMethodOrder.html) annotation on your test class. That will make your tests run in a specified order in every environment (or at least it should :-)).

If you want to do it in the hard way (analyze the source code of the Eclipse JUnit runner), I would advise installing the PDT tools and sources of the plugins first, and also set the *Include all plug-ins from target in Java search* under the *Plug-in Development* options (so you can find the plug-in types easily with *Ctrl+Shift+T/R*).

Then you have the [Plug-in Spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy) which is a rock of a feature: press *Alt+Shift+F2* and click on any element on the UI. Then you get all the info where the given component in defined (alternatively, you can press *Alt+Shift+F1* zo display data of the selected component). An example is below:

[image]